# Reading a text file and separating it with delimiter

Tags: java, arrays, object, delimiter

I am kinda stuck on the following problem and need some guidance. I am trying to read a text file and separate it within a program that I already wrote. The text file will look as follows.

```
2014 Employee lock,John 3000
2015 Salesman Manning,Bill 4000 50000 
2014 Executive Zuck,George 2000 55
```

I know that I can created a array of objects such as:

```
Employee[] employee2014 = new Employee[10];
Employee[] employee2015 = new Employee[10];
```

I am unsure how to use a delimiter to separate the different years and then store the employee information into those years in order. I already wrote three classes for (Employee is parent class to salesman and executive) the program but just need the guidance on the delimiter to store the information in the object. also I don't want to use a array list because my text file only has a limit of 10 items.

Here is an example of one the sub classes Saleman. The parent class Employee and other subclass Executive have the same methods and toString, so I will not post them.

public class Salesman extends Employee {

```
    protected double annualSales;

    public Salesman(int monthlySalary, String name, double annualSales) 
    {
        super(monthlySalary, name);
        this.annualSales = annualSales; 
    }

    @Override
    double annualSalary() {

        double commission = .02;
        commission = commission * annualSales;

        if(commission > 20000)
        {
            commission = 20000;
        } 

        return (super.annualSalary() + commission);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return (super.toString() + "\nAnnual Sales: " + annualSales);
    }
}
```

I will be using a filreader and bufferedreader to read the file, but how will I use a delimiter to separate into the class objects to be read by the years?

Comment: What exactly have you already written (tried)? My first thought is a 2 dimensional Array.

Comment: @DevilsHnd I updated the post, I hope that clarifies it!

Comment: @Ryhart : Try looking at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Comment: @MarkManning thank you for the information. I have been looking for it but still stumped on how to separate it. Delimiter seems like a better choice than tokenizer though......

Comment: @Ryhart : All tokenizing does is to separate out things based on a token.  Your token is a space.  So your first line would return 2014, Employee, lock,John, and 3000.  I know it sounds weird to say "tokenize" but if you look at the webpage you will see what it outputs.  Which is the list of separated values.

Comment: @Ryhart : Go check out https://www.google.com/search?q=%2Bvim+use+list+to+move+to+new+file&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=java+string+token.  Google is your friend. :-)  By the way - the second entry talks about using String.split(<DELIMITER>).  Also a possible answer.

Comment: @Ryhart - If you have the mechanism in place for reading in each file line as a string then you can determine the year for each line by using something like:  if (fileLineString.subString(0,4).equals("2014")) { ... //place contents of fileLineString into an Array ... }

Comment: @DevilsHnd my instructions explicitly say this and you will see why i am confused.......Once all the employee data is read in, a report should be displayed on the console for each of the two years. Each line of the report should contain all original data supplied for each employee together with that employee's annual salary for the year. For each of the two years, an average of all salaries for all employees for that year should be computed and displayed. I am guessing using your way, would complicate the output later.

Comment: @Ryhart : How about you make your array one extra entry long and use that as a unique ID number. Then you can store each record, broken up via the String.split() command into the array.  So the array would be myArray(ID,YEAR,POSITION,PERSON, NUM1,NUM2).  In this way you can sort on the YEAR, POSITION, PERSON, NUM1, or NUM2.  To sort on any of the fields just make a new array with <FIELD> and <ID> so you know how to index into the array.